# German Spitz type?

Tags: dogs

We have this new member of our family.

[image]

[image]

The breeder told us that he is a german spitz small. But when i checked the sizes of that type, if it is above 30 cm height from shoulder then it should be german spitz medium. This bad boy in the picture is 13 weeks old and already 25 cm long from the shoulder. They say dogs usually grow a lot between 4 months-6 months and he is not even 4 months old. Does that mean he is gonna be a larger dog than a spitz small? I mean 5 cm does not seem too much. What do you think guys? Is he a medium size spitz?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you met and interacted with the dam when you picked up your puppy - how large was she?  That's going to be the best indicator of how large your puppy will eventually be.

Given that he is currently at 25 cm it's unlikely he will meet the breed standard for a Klein (small).  The German Spitz has only been recently treated as two separate varieties, thus sizes have not really cemented themselves yet.  Often you find a Klein growing as big as a Mittel and vice versa.